# Grouping Css Selectors (i.e. child OR selectors)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to nest or group selectors together? For example I have the following css:

```
.feature > *:hover > .info,
.feature > .select > .info   {bottom:0;}
.feature > *:hover > .img,
.feature > .select > .img,
.feature > *:hover > .link,
.feature > .select > .link   {top:-25px;bottom:51px;}
```

Is it possible to group many of the selectors in a way similar to the following pseudo CSS (I'm using brackets, but I realise this doesn't work) :

```
.feature > (*:hover,.select) > .info         {bottom:0;}
.feature > (*:hover,.select) > (.img,.link)  {top:-25px;bottom:51px;}
```

I notice that CSS3 has the :not() selector, but I couldn't find an :or() selector.

Comment: I know it is possible using less: http://lesscss.org/ , not sure about vanilla CSS

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you show us an example of LessCSS and this case? I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Added an example with LessCSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`:any()`** is implemented in Fx 4+ as `:-moz-any()` (and Saf 5.1 and Chr 12+ as `:-webkit-any()`, though I never tested on WebKit), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:any

> Note : This pseudo-class is in progress to be standardized in CSS Selectors Level 4 under the name **:matches()**. It is likely that the syntax and name of :-vendor-any() will be changed to reflect it in the near future.

This is quite OK in a media query @-rule (except for recent IE) and otherwise you should **add an HTML class to the element you want to style** and use this class in your CSS selector. Or use a preprocessor where nesting will save you a few repeats.

See @Christoph answer for the near future and `:matches()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's interesting to know this for the future, but it seems any simplifications gained would be negated by vendor specific selectors for the time being.

Comment: True! Still usable if you're writing an extension for a specific browser but doubling each selector when you were trying to shorten them isn't very efficient :) I went the OOCSS way and/or LESS, depending on the project and people involved.

Answer (score 4):

It will be possible with the `:matches()` pseudo class which is defined in [Selectors Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) (which is currently at status Editor's Draft and thus subject to change), which is currently implemented in none of the browsers :-D

Until then you are doomed to write it exactly like you did.

Comment: Sounds like they know it would be helpful, but I guess CSS4 will not be part of HTML 5, or any browser very soon.

Comment: CSS and HTML are two totally different languages anyway. Also, an Editor's Draft is not a state *per se* - there's always an Editor's Draft that is not canon but lives throughout the development of a specification. The stage it's in is Working Draft - the WD is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4).

Comment: @BoltClock They are, however the HTML5 specification includes CSS and JavaScript group of specs.

Comment: @AdrianEaton That's not true, HTML, CSS and EcmaScript are 3 independently developed technologies. HTML 5 is just a buzz word containing a lot of unrelated specifications. It's the same as with CSS3 - there is no CSS3, the 3 accidently came from the selectors module, which is currently at level3. The typical "CSS3" as you know it contains several different modules which are all at different levels.

Comment: That's what they often say about HTML5, but I don't really buy it, it's not like vendors will refuse to support any level 4 CSS modules until HTML5 is complete. In fact, some level 4 selectors have already made it into nightly builds of some browsers.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it is a native CSS solution, or at least will be once supported. Sorry to have started a debate on what is/isn't HTML5!

Comment: @AdrianEaton [Here is an overview](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work) of all CSS Modules currently being worked on. Of course many of the are on level3, but there are several new ones. From CSS3 on, all Modules are developed indepenently.

Comment: @AdrianEaton To be precise, you already could use some sort of grouping, take a look at [Felipe's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15159155/1047823). I don't use this, because 1) it's prefixed and 2) doesn't work in all browsers so it's not of much use. Nonetheless it's noteworthy that this already exists.

Comment: @Christoph, I've switched the accepted answer because it technically provides a current way to do this. However I agree that it is not practical to do this at present (but then neither would :matches() until widely supported)

Comment: @The problem with a prefixed pseudo-class unlike a prefixed css-property is, that you cannot practically use it because it invalidates your whole styledeclaration. It was introduced at the point where it was not known, that such a property would exist in the standard. Now that `:matches()` exists, if implentented by a vendor it will in every case be unprefixed and thus be far more usable. That's why I consider `-*-any()` as no usable solution.

Comment: Ah, I wondered why I had to specify :-moz-placeholder and ::-webkit-input-placeholder separately and couldn't simply use ','

Comment: @Adrian Eaton: Funny story: WebKit makes an exception for pseudo-elements so WebKit pseudo-elements *don't* invalidate the entire style rule, but not for pseudo-classes. All other browsers behave to spec for both.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is unfortunately not possible under normal circumstances. You would have to use a **CSS preprocessor** like:

1. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
2. [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

An example:

```
.feature {
    > *:hover, > .select {
        .info {
            bottom: 0;
        }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the JS libraries. I was wondering if the CSS3 spec had something native. If not it's not too much of an issue for the similar lines, a JS assembly would probably be more to download than a few duplicate classes.

Comment: The fact is that you don't use the JS assembly in production but, if ever, only in development. Depending on the project, I either use the JS, or compile all my `LESS` files on save to normal `CSS`. So you end up with a native, valid, cross-browser CSS. Implementing such a solution right now is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

No, grouping of many css selectors into one line is not possible with CSS.  They have to be broken out each with their own line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sebsemillia could you please clarify in what way this isn't answering: "Can I group CSS selectors?"