# Grouping CSS Selectors & ::selection

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why we **can't** grouping CSS like..

```
p::selection , p::-moz-selection 
{background:transparent;}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/MRyVC/1/

Why we have to select one by one like

```
p::selection       {background:transparent;}
p::-moz-selection  {background:transparent;}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/MRyVC/

Someone can expand this issue ?

Comment: Some browsers just have weird implementations. It's the same for the full screen selector.

Comment: I think because IE doesn't recognize `moz` and same for other browsers.

Comment: both Chrome & Firefox doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/l2aelba/MRyVC/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping Css Selectors (i.e. child OR selectors)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158593/grouping-css-selectors-i-e-child-or-selectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers are [expected](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets) to drop the entire rule if any part of the selector is invalid:

> The selector (see also the section on selectors) consists of everything up to (but not including) the first left curly brace ({). A selector always goes together with a declaration block. When a user agent cannot parse the selector (i.e., it is not valid CSS 2.1), it must ignore the selector and the following declaration block (if any) as well.
>
> CSS 2.1 gives a special meaning to the comma (,) in selectors. However, since it is not known if the comma may acquire other meanings in future updates of CSS, the whole statement should be ignored if there is an error anywhere in the selector, even though the rest of the selector may look reasonable in CSS 2.1.

(Note that as far as a browser is concerned, "valid CSS 2.1" really means "a selector that is understood and supported by the browser".)

Since non-Mozilla browsers don't understand `::-moz-selection`, they have to drop the rule. Since Mozilla browsers don't understand `::selection`, they have to drop the rule as well. It's a lose-lose situation (and another reason why prefixes are unwieldy, especially in selectors).

For the record, I'm surprised this no longer works in Chrome (at least in version 25 on Windows as I just tested anyway). It used to stubbornly parse the selector `p::selection, p::-moz-selection` as simply `p::selection` and apply the rule instead of following the spec, and the developers had reasons for making it so. I wonder what changed...